# Disallow clicking on links in email messages in Mail on macOS?

Tags: macos, mail.app, security

To protect from malicious emails I would like to disable all hyperlinks in received email messages in Apple Mail on macOS.

I know to not click on links in mail messages, but I'd like to make it impossible to click on a link even by accident.

Is there a way/setting/app to disable all links in Mail?

**More context**

The other day I wanted to sell something online. Within minutes I had  an email in my inbox with a supposed "payment confirmation - click here" link. I want to prevent from accidentally opening these links.

Comment: who provides the emails ? google.com others

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. I want to prevent me and other members of my household to be able to click on any link in any message in Mail.

Comment: https://macmost.com/forum/is-it-possible-to-make-links-unclickable-in-apples-mail.html

Comment: OK, let's start with what is your default browser ?

Comment: Chrome can warn you before you visit a site over an insecure connection. This keeps you safer online, especially on public networks like at coffee shops and airports.

Open Chrome menu and select Settings.
Click Privacy and Security and select Security.
Under the Advanced section, turn on Always use Secure Connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this, see a similar question [here](https://macmost.com/forum/is-it-possible-to-make-links-unclickable-in-apples-mail.html). You can [disable link previews](https://ports.macports.org/port/mutt/), but just blocking the links will require a different mail app.

One way is to install [Mutt](https://ports.macports.org/port/mutt/), which is a text based email client without clickable links.

See [here](https://mritunjaysharma394.medium.com/how-to-set-up-mutt-text-based-mail-client-with-gmail-993ae40b0003) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549374/mutt-wont-log-in-login-failed) for a guide.